# Using wp_list_table not listing records

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress

I have 3 tables in my "Membership" database which have info about the members names and teams that they belong to. I am trying to build 2 plugins.

```
   One that lists all of my members, with the exception of a "master" member 
   which is a member of all teams. with the ability to bulk add or delete to 
   or from a team.

   The second is a list of all teams, with the ability to bulk add or delete 
   to or from a members profile.
```

"members" has the members names. It also contains a "master" member with membership to all the teams. It also contains the rest of the membership.

"team" contains all of the team information

"members_team" contains the IDs of the members and connects those IDs to the IDs associated with the teams. One row per team association.

I have been experimenting with an existing code that I will add below. At this point I haven't even been able to display the content of the tables, let alone get into the bulk editing. When it's ran with my editing I keep getting either an empty table or an error.

```
   if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
 require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Members_List extends WP_List_Table {

/** Class constructor */
public function __construct() {

parent::__construct( [
    'singular' => __( 'member', 'sp' ), //singular name of the listed records
    'plural'   => __( 'members', 'sp' ), //plural name of the listed records
    'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
] );

}


/**
 * Retrieve members data from the database
 *
 * @param int $per_page
* @param int $page_number
*
* @return mixed
*/
public static function get_members( $per_page = 5, $page_number = 1 ) {

global $wpdb;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}name";

if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
    $sql .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
}

$sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
$sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;


$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

return $result;
```

}

Comment: Can you include the details of the error you get? Also, I'd suggest addressing the issue in stages, first I'd start with the code that just displays the table to get that working. The less code to debug, the easier it is to find any problems :-) Can you try that and edit your question with the working code ?

Comment: Ok I have included the code that I am trying to use, and edited table names. I am not sure what to edit out to just show the table. I may need to start from scratch but i figured that I could get a better handle on things by using existing code. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: A 500 server error isn't really an error message, its the equivalent of "something went wrong". I'm not suggesting you start from scratch, but that you start with the code you have and remove everything except the code you need to get the table displayed. As I said, its almost impossible to debug a huge chunk of code that has multiple issues, so you simplify as much as possible to remove anything that could affect the core code, and get the basics working. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Now it shows the table with "No members available". There are entries in the table. Sorry, the 500 error is what I was receiving earlier.

Comment: Ok I will work on that and update. Thank You!

Comment: It sounds like could be an error in your SQL if it is not returning any records. We can't debug that as we don't know your database structure, so make sure the query is being generated from the code properly by printing it out and make sure it works in the database

Comment: Agreeing with Fluffy here. Echo or Print out `$sql` and see if the query generated makes sense. Does it run in another client like phpmyadmin? If it looks good and returns results in another client, then we can focus on the rest of the PHP.